# Implicit types with Generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I am currently taking a course on TypeScript and I was wondering the following.  Why is `extends T` the constraint for the function below?  I thought the constraint would be `return param.length` since length is a property of string.

```
function genericInferred<T extends string>(param: T) {
        return param.length;
    }
    console.log(genericInferred("Four"));

    type UUID = string;
    let id: UUID = "123-456";
    console.log(genericInferred(id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly there is no point in using a generic in this particular scenario since you are returning a `number`.

Using `T extends string` makes sense if you want to return a type which depends on the type `T`, as using a generic means that string literals and unions of string literals will keep their specific values instead of being widened to `string`.

```
function genericInferred<T extends string>(param: T): { someKey: T } {
     return {
         someKey: param
     };
}
```

Here we can return `{ someKey: T }` rather than `{ someKey: string }`. Check out the difference in return type in this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOBxApmdAnGEAUADgIbbEC2AXIgM5S5gDmAlIgN4CwAUIr79uighsSTjz4TaccugDS6AJ7USZct0kBfANzcN3bqEiwEiRphx4AkmGA4BAEwA8AFUToAHlEz2atejCYAPiJSCmpnVjFJASERdnVJPhppOUVlULVxPm1dfS4oBUJ0RABlIogYYgAbEv8mXwBeRAAiYmbEAB8WgCN2ruaIZp0ubggEOlpyyqrqMvQK6tqGRkaWtuHR8ahEAUYQKtJqOmXEJtahvLGwCYRippQMLFwCGinq5i1EAHovv2XN67bKAAdzgp2QaHMz3wu32pA%2031%20xwCjABEygAAsBHdTFCrDY7Oh7PhXvNpgifmtmmjtsA4MJwWYnvjbNgHDD0HsDtgKV9kUwgA).

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, a generic constraint is *by definition* what sorts of types the function may be called with. What the function does in its body, or what the function returns, doesn't matter.

You can always identify the constraints simply by looking at the parameter list (including generics). Here, that's:

```
<T extends string>(param: T)
```

So the "constraint" is just that `param` is a `T`, and that `T` is a string.